# If a Shell Script can run no matter which folder I'm in.How can remove it from the environment?

Tags: scripts

I am a green corn in Ubuntu.My question might not be so accurate.The problem I am facing is ：if I run the script 'runzdclient'(the name of the script) directly in terminal,I get a warning 'invalid password or user name'. However, if I click the script and run it ,there aren't any problem.Notice that the script can run irrespective of which the folder I am in . I guess that the script must be in the environment.Here comes the problem: How can I remove the wrong script with the right one in the environment?

Answer (score 2):

Type `which runzdclient` in the terminal.  That will tell you where it's running the script from.  If it's trying to run it from a place you don't expect it to be, you can get rid of that copy and/or overwrite it with the copy that works correctly.